# How to color background of header row in latex

Tags: tables

I have a document with a lot of tables. I would like to change the background color of the header row, for all the tables in whole document in one go without having to change the table codes itselves. Any ideas about how to do that?

For alternating colors I use this script:

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{c5ebec}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{2}{white}{gold}\oldtabular}{\endoldtabular}
```

So I need something like the script above, but only for the header row.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution, with the `etoolbox` package. If *all* your tables  have the same format, you can patch the `tabular` environment. If only some tables have a coloured header, you can use a new `mytabular` environment. In this case, uncomment the commented line in the preamble, and comment the patch. Also I added some vertical padding in rows with the `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} \usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
\colorlet{headercolour}{DarkSeaGreen!40}

%\newenvironment{mytabular}{\rowcolors{1}{\ifnumless{\rownum}{2}{headercolour}{white}}{}\tabular}{\endtabular}

 \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{1}{\ifnumless{\rownum}{2}{headercolour}{white}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{Sc}|}
    \hline
    Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\
    \hline
    A & \cellcolor[gray]{0.5} & D & E \\
    \hline
            & & & F \\
    \hline
            & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution gives a green background to the author when doing `\maketitle`!

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever: Could you post a small complete code reproducing this problem?

Comment: Just put `\maketitle` right after `\begin{document}` in your example to see what I mean. Specifying author with the `\author{<author-name>}` macro in the preamble is optional.

Comment: @Bernard: How can I edit your solution to adjust the cell widths? Is there some place I can insert a p{<width>} option?

Comment: @Leonidas: Yes. Replace `Sc` with `S{p{width}}`. For `X` column types with `tabularx` it is slightly more complex, but it is well explained in the package documentation.