# How to set text color and font type of header row for all tables in LaTeX?

Tags: tables, color, etoolbox, colortbl, rowcolor

I have a document with plenty of tables and I would like to apply the same formatting of the header row for all of them, without making manual modifications for each tabular.

I now use *`\AtBeginEnvironment`* and *`\rowcolors`* from the *`etoolbox`* package based on [Bernard's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304959/139483) for setting the background color in the preamble, but have not found anything similar for the font type and text color.

My current code is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor} %\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\colorlet{headercolour}{DarkSeaGreen}
\colorlet{textcolour}{white}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{1}{\ifnumless{\rownum}{2}{headercolour}{white}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{Sc}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{\color{white}Column1} & \textbf{\color{white}Column2} & \textbf{\color{white}Column3} & \textbf{\color{white}Column4} \\%%set formatting manually for each table
    \hline
    A & B & D & E \\
    \hline
        & & & F \\
    \hline
        & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Header1 & Header2 & Header3\\
        cell1 & cell2 & cell3\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}
\caption{Table2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

With the first table formatted as wanted. That is the style I would like to set for each table automatically.

Any ideas how to do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is something where ConTeXt really shines.  Observe how the actual table content contains zero visual markup

```
\setupTABLE
  [row][first]
  [background=color,
   backgroundcolor=darkgreen,
   color=white,
   style=bold,
   framecolor=black]

\starttext

\startplacetable[title={Table 1}]
  \startTABLE
    \NC Column1 \NC Column2 \NC Column3 \NC Column4 \NC\NR
    \NC A       \NC B       \NC D       \NC E       \NC\NR
    \NC         \NC         \NC         \NC F       \NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopplacetable

\startplacetable[title={Table 2}]
  \startTABLE
    \NC Header1 \NC Header2 \NC Header3 \NC\NR
    \NC cell1   \NC cell2   \NC cell3   \NC\NR
  \stopTABLE
\stopplacetable

\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I propose to define new column types, `L` , `C`, `R`, which incorporate the font  and text colour changes only if we're in first row, since  the `[table]` option of `xcolor` defines a `\rownum` counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\colorlet{headercolour}{DarkSeaGreen}
\colorlet{textcolour}{yellow}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\rowcolors{1}{\ifnumequal{\rownum}{1}{headercolour}{white}}{}}%
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\ifnumequal{\rownum}{1}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{textcolour}}}Sl}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\ifnumequal{\rownum}{1}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{textcolour}}}Sc}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\ifnumequal{\rownum}{1}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{textcolour}}}Sr}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{5pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{C}|}%
    \hline
Column1 & Column2 & Column3 & Column4 \\%%set formatting manually for each table
    \hline
    A & B & D & E \\
    \hline
        & & & F \\
    \hline
        & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{| CCC|}%
        \hline
 Header1 & Header2 & Header3 \\
  cell1 & cell2 & cell3\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Table2}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]